# using generalized text to search inside html source code

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm working on a small project where I have small files that will be fed to my program from a folder.

These files will be used to  check websites for a user

so, for example, I want to look up a user on Reddit, Twitch and more sites. I could use this tool if I had the configs for the sites I wanted to check the username on.

```
def userCheck(link, user, isSuccess):
    link = link.replace("<USERNAME>", user)
    isSuccess = isSuccess.replace("<USERNAME>", user)
    print(isSuccess)
    print(link)
    html = requests.get(link)
    print(html)
    page_source = html.text
    count = page_source.count(isSuccess)
    print(count)
    if count > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    outFile =  open("outputs.txt","w+")
    outFile.write(page_source)
    outFile.close()

print(userCheck("https://reddit.com/u/<USERNAME>", "1r0nk3y", "<h1 class=\"_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m\"><USERNAME></h1>"))
```

in theory, my code should look through the HTML for the isSuccess variable (replaced by the username) and successfully return true in this certain case. Yes, I know I could work with response codes but some websites will give a good code for a bad user.

here's my output:

```
<h1 class=_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m>1r0nk3y</h1>
https://reddit.com/u/1r0nk3y
<Response [502]>
0
False
```

I believe the main dilemma I am facing here is that I don't want to use something like bs4 for this. it needs to be much simpler. but if a website needs a much more advanced keyword or phrase to validate it was a successful lookup, I will need to use things with quotes in them

any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why not use regular expressions? You could create a list of regex objects for each site specifying where a username would appear and match those against the input. This way you wouldn't have to parse the whole page and it would be much faster

Comment: i would consider using xpath which has functions to search nodes using the text present on the page_source. lxml has xpath options. but i think regex would be much faster.